# The correct function to loop to text file

Tags: python, function, loops

Could anyone help with the correct way to loop to a text file. I have an issue with my code at the moment where it is writing task numbers to a text file but all the numbers are returning task 1. My second task is not returning task 2 and the third task not returning task 3. They are all returning task 1. I would like for the task number to change every time i add a task to the text file. Would a simple way to be able to call on a specific task later in the code be possible?

task example:

> User assigned to task:
>
> jack
>
> Task Title:
>
> jog
>
> Task Description:
>
> Go jogging
>
> Task Due Date:
>
> 2020-02-08
>
> Date Assigned:
>
> 2020-02-07
>
> Task Completed:
>
> No

requested output:

> User assigned to task 1:
>
> jack
>
> Task Title:
>
> jog
>
> Task Description:
>
> Go jogging
>
> Task Due Date:
>
> 2020-02-08
>
> Date Assigned:
>
> 2020-02-07
>
> Task Completed:
>
> No

The code i have so far is as follows. It is writing numbers to the text file but they are all labelled task 1 and the next task is not changing to task 2:

```
count = 0

def add_task(count):
 if menu == "a" or menu == "A":
    with open( 'user.txt' ) as fin :    
        usernames = [i.split(',')[0] for i in fin.readlines() if len(i) > 3]
        task = input ("Please enter the username of the person the task is assigned to.\n")
    while task not in usernames :
        task = input("Username not registered. Please enter a valid username.\n")

    else:
        task_title = input("Please enter the title of the task.\n")
        task_description = input("Please enter the task description.\n")
        task_due = input("Please input the due date of the task. (yyyy-mm-dd)\n")
        date = datetime.date.today()
        task_completed = False
        if task_completed == False:
            task_completed = "No"
        else:
            task_completed = ("Yes")
        with open('tasks.txt', 'a') as task1:
            count = count + 1
            task1.write("\nUser assigned to task" + str(count) + "\n" + task + "\nTask Title :"  + "\n" + task_title + "\n" + "Task Description:\n" + task_description + "\n" + "Task Due Date:\n" + task_due + "\n" + "Date Assigned:\n" + str(date) + "\n" + "Task Completed:\n" + task_completed + "\n")
            print("The new assigned task has been saved")
add_task(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `count` is in the global scope, and when you run `count = count + 1` in your function, you change it only for the local function scope. if you want the function to change a global variable, you need to use the `global` statement.

Add this as the first line of `add_task` function:

```
global count
```

And remove count from the function parameter. (so `add_task` function will be called without passing the count to it)

Now when you run `count = count + 1`, it will change the count variable from the global scope.

However, [using global variables is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil), a better approach would be to use a class, and save count as class variable:

```
class TaskCreator():
    task_count = 0
    @classmethod
    def add_task(cls):
        if menu == "a" or menu == "A":
            with open( 'user.txt' ) as fin :    
                usernames = [i.split(',')[0] for i in fin.readlines() if len(i) > 3]
                task = input ("Please enter the username of the person the task is assigned to.\n")
            while task not in usernames :
                task = input("Username not registered. Please enter a valid username.\n")

            else:
                task_title = input("Please enter the title of the task.\n")
                task_description = input("Please enter the task description.\n")
                task_due = input("Please input the due date of the task. (yyyy-mm-dd)\n")
                date = datetime.date.today()
                task_completed = False
                if task_completed == False:
                    task_completed = "No"
                else:
                    task_completed = ("Yes")
                with open('tasks.txt', 'a') as task1:
                    cls.task_count += 1
                    task1.write("\nUser assigned to task" + str(cls.task_count) + "\n" + task + "\nTask Title :"  + "\n" + task_title + "\n" + "Task Description:\n" + task_description + "\n" + "Task Due Date:\n" + task_due + "\n" + "Date Assigned:\n" + str(date) + "\n" + "Task Completed:\n" + task_completed + "\n")
                    print("The new assigned task has been saved")

TaskCreator.add_task()
```

Comment: Thank you Moshe. I'm gonna definitely give it a try... Ive been stuck on this for days

Comment: A much better solution is to not have global variables.

Comment: @tripleee I agree, I've added another solution.

Comment: @Moshe finally had chance to run the code but still only returns task 1 even after adding a second task...any ideas?